# How to create custom sticky notification without jailbreak in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, sticky

According to my app requirement i have create custom notification using **Notification Content Extention and Interface** now i just want to make it sticky,Like it does not removable from the notification center till i remove it through my code.

Here is the reference image of sticky notification :

[image]

So can you please help me to find some alternate solution of it to make custom notification without jailbreak ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't force a notification to remain onscreen.  Notifications are shown by iOS for a limited time before they disappear.   Notifications remain in the notification center (shown by swiping down) until cleared by the user or your app.

Comment: The alternate solution of my issue is to add widget like any of music applications(Ganna,saavan) which display player in notification center on tap of play button and hide from Notification center on pause button tap. So have you any idea about it ?